# Heat Tape on Empty CPVC Pipe

Tags: plumbing, electric-heat, cpvc

I'm planning on installing heat tape on the CPVC pipe that feeds to my garden hose.

It occurred to me that I or future owners may choose to turn off the water and bleed the pipe.

I realize I could just unplug the heat tape but my question is is there a risk to just leaving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heat tape really only gets warm not “HOT” enough to damage pvc or cpvc I have seen heat tape that was improperly installed, not self regulating and it was crossed over itself several times, one of those areas melted the heat tape but the controller blew prior to damage to the pipe and that was standard cold water pvc (cpvc can handle higher heat)